# Numerical Difficulty in Evaluating a Function.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I was asked, given the function $$f(x)=\ln{\left(x-\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)},\ x \gg
 1,$$ to discuss the numerical difficulty in evaluating for the given values of x.

Would it be correct to say that, since $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(x-\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}=0,$$

and due to the finite accuracy of floating point arithmetic, that there will eventually be a loss of significance that'll make the subtraction zero, and thus make the function undefined?

Is there anything else that could be said?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, I've fixed it thank you.

Comment: Hint: look at the asymptotic behaviour for large but **finite** $x$.

Comment: $f(x)=-\text{arccosh}(x)$, hence $f(x)$ can be evaluated through Newton's method

$$ z_{n+1} = z_n - \frac{\cosh(z_n)-x}{\sinh(z_n)} $$
with starting point $z_0=\log(2x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider 
$$A=x-\sqrt{x^{2}-1}$$ there will be already problems  because of what you properly wrote.
This is why it is better to write
$$A=x-\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\times \frac{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1} } {x+\sqrt{x^{2}-1} }=\frac 1{ x+\sqrt{x^{2}-1}} \sim\frac{1}{2 x}$$ which will not make any problem; the same for $\log(A)$.

Comment: Nice tranformation to the denominator.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze and ClaudeLeibovici Would $\ln{\left(x-\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)}=\ln{\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}}=-\ln{\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}$ be okay as well?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze This is pretty standard when working with numerical aspects (what I started doing 61 years ago).

Comment: @AlexD. When $x$ is large, $\sqrt{x^2-1}\sim x$ for the first and yes for the second question.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Thank you both for your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

The error of evaluating $x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is about the same as the error of evaluating $|x|+\sqrt{x^2+1}$ which is somewhere around $(1+2|x|)\mu$. While the exact value in the second case has the same growth for large $x$, in the original expression it goes to zero like $\frac1{2x}$, so that the relative error will grow unbounded like $\sim4x^2\mu$.

[image]

At the point where $x^2\mu>1$, that is, $x>10^8$, the subtraction of $1$ under the root has no longer any effect and the value of the original expression is zero, giving a relative error of $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry newbie question, but what does the $\mu$ represent?

Comment: The machine constant of the floating point number type. It gives a bound on the relative accuracy of any floating point operation. The absolute error of any floating point evaluation of a functional expression can be estimated as a multiple of $\mu$ where the factor is the value of a modified expression where every sum or difference is replaced by the sum of the absolute values of its terms. This works for instance very well in explaining the relative error of polynomial evaluation close to its roots.

Answer (score 1):

I can be useful to write down the relative error in the computed result in terms of the condition number (independent of the algorithm/ expression used to compute $f$) and of the truncation errors committed in each step of the algorithm (let's say $k$ steps). You can obtain, as a first order approximation an expression of the type
$$
\varepsilon_f \approx Q_0(x) \varepsilon_x + \sum_{i=1}^k Q_k(x) e_{a_k}
$$

The numerical stability is only guaranteed if all coefficients $Q_0, \cdots, Q_k$ are bounded.

In this case, if you assume that $f$ is computed using the algorithm
$$
z_1 = x^2-1, \quad z_2 = \sqrt{z_1}, \quad z_3 = x-z_2, \quad z_4= \log z_3
$$

You get that

\begin{align*}
\varepsilon_{z_4} = & -\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1} \cdot \log(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})} \varepsilon_x -\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{2 \log(x -\sqrt{x^2-1})\cdot (x-\sqrt{x^2-1})} e_{a_1}\\
& -\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\log(x -\sqrt{x^2-1})\cdot (x-\sqrt{x^2-1})} e_{a_2}+\dfrac{1}{\log(x-\sqrt {x^2-1})} e_{a_3} + e_{a_4}
\end{align*}

Looking at these coefficients, you'll see that $Q_2$ and $Q_3$ are unbounded ($x\to +\infty$) and so the algorithm is unstable.